# Make div sit underneath another with relation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make the nav arrows sit underneath an image carousel in a fixed location that will still allow them to move responsively when the browser size is adjusted?[image: browser 1] [image: browser 2] Right now I can get the arrows to sit where I want them only at a certain browser size but when it is adjusted it moves not in conjunction with the image. I'm using Glide (http://jedrzejchalubek.com/glide/) for the image carousel.

```
.slider-arrow {
display:block;
position:fixed;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;

}

.slider-arrow--right {  
margin-left: 60%;

}

.slider-arrow--left {
margin-left: 40%;

}
```

Comment: One way to achieve this is with media queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. The easiest way will probably be to put the arrows inside the same div the image sits in. Then you might want to set text-align=left style for the div to make the arrows left justify. I would however recommend to get a better understanding of CSS layout before you continue. Once you understand how relative, fixed, and absolute positioning work, things will get much easier. See this link: http://learnlayout.com/position.html

```
#imgdiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    text-align: left;
}

<div id="imgdiv">
    <img src="img1.jpg"><br><img src="arrow1.jpg">&nbsp;<img src="arrow2.jpg">
</div>
```